# Visual Studio encountered an unexpected network error and can’t contact the Microsoft account service

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I confirgured my windows store DEV account couple of days ago. I have developed some store apps and I need to publish it in windows store. When I try to create the App packages using Visual studio 2012 Ultimate It gives me this error

Visual Studio encountered an unexpected network error and can’t contact the Microsoft account service
I followed the solution mentioned in this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/01/15/visual-studio-2012-throws-an-error-saying-visual-studio-encountered-an-unexpected-network-error-and-can-t-contact-the-microsoft-account-service-when-you-try-to-create-app-packages-for-the-windows-store.aspx. But it didn't work out, still getting the same error.

Comment: this is not connected to a LAN, I'm working with my personal PC, with mobile broadband. it's works fine. I'm using that internet connection to do any other work in this PC

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you need to open the Internet Explorer (not others browsers) and access https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf. A popup will appear. Check the option "In the future, do not show this warning" and click OK. You should be able to complete you task. For more details, check this [post](http://talkitbr.com/2015/09/02/associando-app-com-a-loja/)